# Insufficient privileges message shown for approval page

Tags: approval-process, insufficient-privileges

I've created an approval process that has specific users assigned as approvers. These approvers receive emails saying that there is a request awaiting their approval. However when they click on the link that is supposed to open the approval page; they see Insufficient Privileges error.

Approval page is the one provided by SalesForce (I've not created any custom page).

On page 5 of 6 (Select Fields to Display on Approval Page Layout) option "Allow approvers to access the approval page only from within the Salesforce application." is selected. I cannot see any way to assign security roles to the approval page anywhere else.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you checked if approver has View permission on that record ? Try to open same record by approver's login, In order to approve record, approver must needs to have read permission.

Comment: Hi Jeetendra, Thanks for your reply. That user is able to see the record. but when he tries to lcik the url having https://salesforce.com/p/process/ProcessInstanceWorkitemWizardStageManager?id=<id> he gets insufficient privileges. Is there a way to assign provileges to this ProcessInstanceWorkItemWizard?

Answer (score 4):

The answer above is not correct.  You don't need edit permission to the record in order to approve it - only read permission as stated in sales force documentation:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_processing_approval_requests_parent.htm&type=5

I have also tested this in my sales force org.

Answer (score 2):

The user needs Read and Edit Permissions to the record being approved in order to have permission to this UI.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that I would recommend checking. First (as @Jitendra Zaa pointed out), make sure the approver has access to the both the object and the specific record. There is a good [guide from Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_insufficient_privileges_map.htm&language=en_US) on how to do this troubleshooting.

The Button Click Admin blog also has [a great post](http://www.buttonclickadmin.com/how-to-deal-with-the-salesforce-insufficient-privileges-error/) on how to handle this error message and things to check for when troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will check roles/privileges assigned to user and get back on this forum.

Comment: Reading your note above, it's possible that the approver has read permissions but not edit permissions. Are they able to edit the record independently of the approval process?

Comment: Button Click Admin blog post is gone!  any updated resources for things to help troubleshoot this?